# Which transformation did Future Gohan use in Dragon Ball Heroes episode 50?

Tags: dragon-ball-heroes

In Dragon Ball Heroes episode 50,

> Future Gohan, Goku and Bardock are fighting Demigra I believe and counter an attack of him with kamehamehas. Then, Goku which was fighting as super saiyan blue kaioken turns into Ultra Instict, Bardock which was transformed in Super Saiyan 3 turns into Super Saiyan 4, and Future Gohan who was fighting as super saiyan power ups, and apparently there is some light blue flashes in the aura. Did he turn Super Saiyan Rage or any other transformation?

Which transformation did Future Gohan use in Dragon Ball Heroes episode 50?

Answer (score 1):

Future Gohan powered up to Super Saiyan 2.